# windows phone Image Translation (movement/animation)

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Im trying to animate a image that moves from the right side of the screen to the left, i guess thats what translate is for, but not really sure how it works, or whats the best solution. So far i have this:

```
        <Image Height="50" Width="50" Source="/Assets/Img/cloud.png" Stretch="Uniform">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="p1Translate" X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
```

Which is nothing! 
So can someone help me, translate the cloud.png just in the X axis?

Greets,
José Correia

Comment: Use blend and create a sample animation. you will get your answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using the `CompositeTransform` for your image? You could use `Blend` to come up with a storyboard animation.

[XAML storyboard animation moving images from outside viewport-windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047295/)

For further reference:

[Images Animation By Using Story Board in Windows Phone 8/8.1](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823622/Images-Animation-By-Using-Story-Board-in-Windows-P)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this article should answer all your questions: [Quickstart: Animations for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206955(v=vs.105).aspx)

While you can use the RenderTransform in order to position objects relative to where the layouting engine puts them the easier way is to place the Control you want to move around inside a Canvas which directly attaches position properties to that Control. This is shown in one of the samples in the article I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, heres how i did it:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="-598.826"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Image x:Name="image" Source="/Assets/Img/bg_cloud.png" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="50,50" Width="70" Height="40" Margin="497,596,-87,164">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
```

And Blend really helped me out!

Best regards,
José Correia